# Matching all elements in nested lists (irrespective of position) and returning matches with indexes

Tags: r, list, matching, nested-lists

I have two lists x and y created from

```
x1 = list(c(1,2,3,4))
x2 = list(c(seq(1, 10, by = 2)))
x<- list(x1,x2)

x
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

and y,

```
y1 = list(c(5, 6, 7, 8))
y2 = list(c(9, 7, 5, 3, 1))
y <- list(y1, y2)

y
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 5 6 7 8


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 9 7 5 3 1
```

So basically, I want to get matches of x into y so I should just get '1 3 5 7 9' actually being a match. I am also needing indexes.

I have tried, I want to match the values irrespective of the position each x[[ ]] with each y[[ ]].

```
Matches <- x[x %in% y]
IDX <- which(x %in% y)
```

This does not work....

I would like something that can return matches of the same elements irrespective of positions per each list. This would be a rough idea of what I need...

```
  matches

        [1] False

        [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Thanks in advance, appreciate all the help.

Comment: If you can provide a reproducible example with a subset of your data, that would help people work on your problem and clarify what you mean "matching exact elements that may be in different positions". Thanks :)

Comment: If you want to match `x` and `y` why not `unlist` them first? Or do you want to match `x[[1]]` and `y[[1]]`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

So, you have made list of lists, which is quite confusing to work with, you could have totally avoided using `c`, so you can have, `x <- c(x1, x2)` to get list of vectors, which is much more easy to work with.

But since you provided with list of lists, I will work with that.

Now back to solving your question:

```
flags <- lapply(Map(`%in%`, unlist(x, recursive = F), unlist(y, recursive=F)),all) 


k <- lapply(1:length(x), function(i)ifelse(unlist(flags)[i] == TRUE, 
                                          list(unlist(x, recursive=F)[[i]]), 
                                          unlist(flags[i]))) 

unlist(k, recursive = F)  #Final Output
```

**Logic:**

- Mapping each items in list using %in% to see if an element
  contains item of other elements, if all the elements are present it
  will return a TRUE or a FALSE, In your case it would return FALSE and
  TRUE respectively.
- Here we are iterating to the lists of x by using flag as a filter
  criteria you can make another list k, when value of flag created in
  earlier step is TRUE it will copy back the contents of x, however
  when FALSE it will remain as FALSE
- Final step to your answer, unlist k again to convert into a list
  of vectors using unlist with recursive = F.

**Output:**

```
  # [[1]]
   # [1] FALSE

   # [[2]]
   # [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help and explanation :)